# why does Trunc(date) >= trunc(sysdate) - 1 return different results in similar queries for the same data in Oracle Sql

Tags: oracle, date, truncate

I have this query. The main part to look at are the columns for QUANTITY_VALUEand DATE_FLAG.

If in PROBLEM_TABLE I have a QUANTITY of 50 and an DATE OF SYSDATE+1, I would expect 50 for DATE and 'Y' for DATE_FLAG.

However, occasionally this is not the case. I will get Null and 'N' for the returned values.

```
BASE.NBR,BASE.ID,
(SELECT QUANTITY FROM PROBLEM_TABLE PT
    WHERE PT.QUANTITY > 0 AND PT.ID IN(1,2,3)
    AND TRUNC(PT.DATE) >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1 
    AND PT.NBR =123 AND PT.ID=456) QUANTITY_VALUE,
(SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(NVL(PT.QTY,0)) > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END 
    FROM PROBLEM_TABLE PT
    WHERE PT.QUANTITY > 0 AND PT.ID IN(1,2,3)
        AND TRUNC(PT.DATE) >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1 
        AND PT.NBR =123 AND PT.ID=456) DATE_FLAG  
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT MAIN_T.NBR, MAIN_T.ID
    FROM MAINT_TABLE MAINT_T
    JOIN (SELECT MAX(MAINT_T_ID) AS MAINT_T_ID,NBR,ID
            FROM MAINT_TABLE
            WHERE NBR=123 AND S_ID=1
            GROUP BY NBR,ID
            ) SUB_T ON SUB_T.MAINT_T_ID=MAINT_T.MAINT_T_ID
    WHERE MAIN_T.ID IS NOT NULL
) BASE
```

If I run just one of the scalar queries on its own, I will get the quantity of 50 or 'Y'

```
SELECT PT.QUANTITY FROM PROBLEM_TABLE PT
    WHERE PT.QUANTITY > 0 AND PT.ID IN(1,2,3)
    AND TRUNC(PT.DATE) >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1 
    AND PT.NBR =123 AND PT.ID=456
```

Now Here is the interesting part. If I remove the "TRUNC" from the left hand side of either scalar query, both will return with correct values.

For Example, Below I have change "TRUNC(PT.DATE)" to just PT.DATE in the QUANTITY_VALUE query but not the DATE_FLAG query.

```
BASE.NBR,BASE.ID,
(SELECT QUANTITY FROM PROBLEM_TABLE PT
    WHERE PT.QUANTITY > 0 AND PT.ID IN(1,2,3)
    AND PT.DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1 
    AND PT.NBR =123 AND PT.ID=456) QUANTITY_VALUE,
(SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(NVL(PT.QTY,0)) > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END 
    FROM PROBLEM_TABLE PT
    WHERE PT.QUANTITY > 0 AND PT.ID IN(1,2,3)
        AND TRUNC(PT.DATE) >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1 
        AND PT.NBR =123 AND PT.ID=456) DATE_FLAG  
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT MAIN_T.NBR, MAIN_T.ID
    FROM MAINT_TABLE MAINT_T
    JOIN (SELECT MAX(MAINT_T_ID) AS MAINT_T_ID,NBR,ID
            FROM MAINT_TABLE
            WHERE NBR=123 AND S_ID=1
            GROUP BY NBR,ID
            ) SUB_T ON SUB_T.MAINT_T_ID=MAINT_T.MAINT_T_ID
            WHERE MAIN_T.ID IS NOT NULL
            ) BASE
```

The result from this query is '50' and 'Y' dispite not changing any data.

The simple fix to this is removing the trunc from the left hand side of this query, but I dont understand WHY this is happening.

Comment: What is the `pt.date` value when there is a problem?  What is the data type of `pt.date`?  Is it a `date` (in which case it will always have a time component-- is that time component midnight?)?  Or is this a `varchar2` or something else?

Comment: In your second scalar, you lack a table alias and yet make references to both PR and PT. Is that an oversight? Correct those so you have a unique alias not shared by anything in the parent query and make sure the column references all use the right alias. That would be a start. We aren't beyond 19c in our company where this can't happen, but if you're on 21c or something where Oracle might have some new subquery rewriting thing going on that could possibly cause alias contamination between the two subqueries... I'd just want to rule that out.

Comment: PT.DATE is a DATE column.

Comment: Sorry I messed up the alias on that second scalar in this example. I was trying to make it easier to read the question.

Comment: I ran into this issue on the 21st, the value of DATE was Feb 22nd 1PM 2023.